# QAbstractItemModel::columnCount - variable column count for each row

Tags: c++, c++17, qabstractitemmodel, qt5.11

We are implementing an QAbstractItemModel structure as shown in diagram below and would like that;

- node A to contains 3 data columns
- node B to contains 8 data columns
- node C to contains 5 data columns

[image]

However, when looking at the signature for QAbstractItemModel::columnCount it is unclear how to implement the above requirement. It is difficult to determine that node A shall have 3 columns, node B shall have 8 columns and node C shall have 5 columns give only the parent index.

> ***int QAbstractItemModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const***
>
> Returns the number of columns for the children of the given parent.
>
> In most subclasses, the number of columns is independent of the parent.
>
> [QAbstractItemModel::columnCount](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#columnCount)

This type of problem must surely be possible to solve using QAbstractItemModel. What am I doing wrong or not thinking about? Appreciate any input on the matter.

Comment: `QAbstractItemModel` is an adapter design pattern. So if you need help you should explain what kind of data you have and what to show in a `QTreeView`. Then we can give you an advice how to implement each parts of adapter `QAbstractItemModel`. In a  `QTreeeView` number of columns remains constant.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible for different children of the same parent to have different column count. At least with the standard QTreeView.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you, but I implemented a Tree Model to figure out how to write models. It's at my github: https://github.com/jplflyer/qt-TreeViewDemo

To address your specific question: You're passed a `QModelIndex` object, and you have to figure out what data that is pointing to and use that to determine the number of children.

You already should have code that takes a `QModelIndex` and returns the column data, so you can tap into the same code to know what to return.

Comment: In the QAbstractItemModel::data(..) method we are provided the QModelIndex to the actual data. In this scenario I feel we have all the information needed to return the correct data. However, in the QAbstractItemModel::columnCount(..) method we are provided with the QModelIndex to the parent. In this scenario I struggle to understand when I should return 3 (node A) or 8 (node B) or 5 (node C).

Comment: I had to do a lot of experimenting. Perhaps for now return a constant and do some debug output. See what the index really points to.